# How to create Scala class with my IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am learning SCALA from Martin Odersky coursera course.The problem is that my IDEA is "pure" java, and his is sbt based.Unlike his,my drop-down menu does not have Java class and Scall class.Screenshot form coursera

[image]

How to solve this problem?
When I go settings,plugins,it seems that Scala plugin is installed

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the Scala plugins to IDEA?

Comment: Install `Scala` plugin in your `IDEA`

Comment: @mlidal Take a look at my edit,I think it is installed.

Comment: as far as I remember, coursera uses the Scala IDE (by eclipse) and you are using Intellij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the project it needs to be a Scala project, not a Java project